# Convertir Variables numéricas ddmmaaaa/aaaammdd a Formato Fecha - Python

Tags: python, datetime

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Fecha_Nac'] = ['26031934','2091944','2091944']
df1['Fecha_Alta'] = ['20181127','20171017','20180622']
df1['Fecha_Baja'] = ['20200713','20180425','20190701']
```

**Nota 1:** Nótese que la Fecha_Nac tiene un orden de Día/Mes/Año y la Fecha Alta y Baja tienen un orden de Año/Mes/Día.

Intento convertirlos en fecha y no lo logro, hasta el momento he intentado varias opciones, van 2 de estos intentos:

> Intento 1

```
formato = '%d/%m/%Y'
df['Fecha_Nac'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha_Nac'], format=formato)
df['Fecha_Alta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha_Alta'], format=formato)
df['Fecha_Baja'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha_Baja'], format=formato)
```

> Intento 2

```
df['Fecha_Nac'] = df['Fecha_Nac'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['Fecha_Alta'] = df['Fecha_Alta'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['Fecha_Baja'] = df['Fecha_Baja'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Gracias por vuestra colaboración

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la respuesta:

```
dates = list(df['Fecha Nac'])

FN = pd.DataFrame(data=list(enumerate(dates, start=1)), columns=["id","int_date"])

FN[["Fecha_Nac"]] = FN[["int_date"]].applymap(str).applymap(lambda s: "{}/{}/{}".format(s[0:2],s[3:4], s[4:8]))

print(FN)
```

Dejo mi respuesta por acá por si acaso puedo colaborar.

Saludos

Comment: ¡Genial! Me alegra que encontraras la respuesta. Gracias por compartirla con la comunidad :)

Comment: Gracias, ahí vamos, recorriendo la curva de aprendizaje. Gracias por tu comentario. Un saludo